# Javascript TypeError: ... is not a Constructor - How can I make Constructors from Constructors?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do object inheritance in Javascript - is the following possible to do in javascript?

Grandparent Object:

```
var shape=function(paramOpts){
    this.opts={x:0,y:0,h:10,w:10};
    $.extend(true,this.opts,paramOpts);
    this.sides=0;
    this.fill='#fff';
    this.outline='#000';
    // some methods
};
```

Parent Object

```
var square=new shape();
square.sides=4;
```

Child Object

```
var redbox=new square();
redbox.fill='#f00';
```

Running this I get the error `TypeError: square is not a Constructor`.

How can I make `square` a Constructor?

Comment: Constructor functions and prototype are explained here.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711 you could use only object.create but have to run an init function to initialize instance specific members and call parent to re use parent constructor/init

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create `square` you don't get `Function` returned as your prototype, you get `shape`.

There are several ways you can inherit like this, personally; I like to use `Object.create()` i.e

```
function shape(paramOpts){
  this.opts={x:0,y:0,h:10,w:10};
  $.extend(true,this.opts,paramOpts);
  this.sides=0;
  this.fill='#fff';
  this.outline='#000';
  // some methods
};

var square = Object.create(shape);
square.sides = 4;

var redbox = Object.create(square);
redbox.fill = '#f00';
```

Support for `Object.create` goes as far back as IE9 but no farther, there are plenty of shims that will do this for you though.

If you don't want to use a shim you can do it the classical way, your shape definition's methods would be defined on the `prototype` chain for `shape` i.e:

```
shape.prototype.setFill = function shape_fill(colour) {
  this.fill = colour;
  return this;
};
```

And your following definitions of `square` and `redsquare` would simply "leech" the prototype from `shape` like below:

```
function square(){}
square.prototype = shape.prototype;

function redbox() {}
redbox.prototype = square.prototype;
```

I hope this helps and I've been clear :)

If I've not been clear, there's loads and loads of information on the various `Object.` functions on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

**edit**

Continuation from my last comment below, you can add a `super` method to your prototype to fire the construct like below:

```
redbox.prototype.super = square.prototype.super = function super() {
  return shape.call(this);
};
```

With that you should be able to call `square.super()` to run the `shape` construct and you can do the same for `redbox` to do the same.

You can also include the `shape.call(this);` code inside your `square` and `redbox` function definitions to do it, probably neater but it's your choice in honesty, personal taste lends my favour to prototype.

Comment: `Object.create()` still kicks out the `is not a Constructor` error. I console.log the typeof shape and square (square made thru Object.create) and I get `function` and `Function` (the later being a Function Object I believe?)

I get more success with the prototype method you describe, but then I cant access the parent object (or its methods/properties) from within any additional methods I add to the child object. Instead of `this` referring to the object I am adding the methods to, `this` refers to the method I am adding.

Comment: Ahh okay, that's my bad. If you try `square.prototype.constructor = shape;` You should have more success.

Comment: still failing - when I try that and console.log `square` it comes up as an empty function?

Comment: Interesting, okay there is another solution but it's a bit code heavy. I'll add it as an edit to my answer for you.

Answer (score 2):

**square is not a function**

> You cannot instantiate from variable , However , you can instantiate
>   from function .

Another thing , **shape is not a GrandParentObject , It is a constructor** in you context(=Class in OOP terminology) .

Use this function :

```
function inherits(base, extension)
{
   for ( var property in base )
   {


         extension[property] = base[property];


   }
}
```

Shape Class:

```
var shape=function(paramOpts){
    this.opts={x:0,y:0,h:10,w:10};
    $.extend(true,this.opts,paramOpts);
    this.sides=0;
    this.fill='#fff';
    this.outline='#000';
    // some methods'
    return this ; 
};
```

Grandparent Object :

```
var shape1=new shape();
```

Parent Object

```
 var square=new shape();
   inherits(shape1,square)
    square.sides=4;
```

Child Object

```
    var redbox=new shape();
  inherits(square,redbox)
    redbox.fill='#f00';
```

**UPDATE:**

I note your comment in Shape Class (`//some methods`) . However , if you talk about OO, Adding Methods to Your shape Class , it will be as following (Using Prototype) :

```
shape.prototype.Perimeter=function(){
   return this.opts.w * this.opts.h ;
}
```

Then you can apply it in your object shape1

```
shape1.Perimeter(); // 10*10=100
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example of inheritance in JavaScript:

```
// Parent class
function Shape (sides) {
    this.sides = sides;
    this.fill='#fff';
}
// Child class
function Square (fill) {
    // run the Parent class' constructor
    Shape.call(this, 4);
    this.fill = fill;
}
// Instantiate Child class
var redbox = new Square('#f00');
```

Comment: Better to use object.create instead of setting child prototype to an instance of parent http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063394/prototypical-inheritance-writing-up/16063711#16063711